# MPI tree structured communication

Tags: c, mpi

I wrote this code in order to trace and inspect the communication in an MPI model. The idea here is that, if there are for example 8 proceccors,  node-0- will communicate with itself and node-4-. Furthermore node-4-
will communicate with node-6-, and node-2- on the other side of tree will communicate with node-3-. Here is the image of this scheme.
[image]

I wrote the code below to see how nodes pass an array of elements to each other. Line 31 to 33 calculates the parameters of each node. It's like binary tree but a little bit different.

Here is the problem: When I execute the code each child node returns to its parent some garbage together with the array elements. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Could any one give me a hand?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include<math.h>

void print_array(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
/***********************************************************************/
void copyarray(int a[] ,int start_a , int end_a, int* b, int size_b)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size_b;i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[start_a];
        start_a++;
        if (start_a > end_a)
            break;
    }
}
/***************************************************/
void tree (int arr[],int size,int level)
{
    int rank;
    int numOfcores;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numOfcores);
    int parent = rank & ~(1 << level);
    int next = level - 1;
    int rightChild = rank | (1 << (level - 1));
    
         if(level>0)
         {
                printf("\n enterig the divid process\n");
                printf("\n i am the node %d with te Rank of %d and height of %d \n",rank,rank,level);
                 int mid = (int)(size/2);///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                 print_array(arr,size);
                 tree(arr,mid,next);
                 int rightsize=size-mid;////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                 int* rightArray =(int*)calloc(rightsize,sizeof(int));
                 if(rightArray==NULL)
                 return;
                 copyarray(arr,mid,size,rightArray,rightsize);////////////////////////////////////////
                 int massage[2];
                 massage[0]=next;
                 massage[1]=rightsize;
                 MPI_Send(massage,2,MPI_INT,rightChild,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                 MPI_Send(rightArray,rightsize,MPI_INT,rightChild,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);   
                 
                 int* recvArray = (int*)calloc(rightsize,sizeof(int));

                 if(parent!=rank)
                 {
                  printf("\n i am the node %d withe height of  %d and i send my array to parent %d ",rank,level,parent);
                  MPI_Send(arr,size,MPI_INT,parent,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                 }
                 MPI_Recv(recvArray,size,MPI_INT,rightChild,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                 printf("\n i am the parent node %d with the height of %d and i recieved form %d the array :\n ",rank,level,rightChild);
                 print_array(recvArray,size);
                 free(rightArray);
                 free(recvArray);
         } 
         
         else 
         {
            printf("\n i am the node %d with the height of %d and i have the array of : \n ",rank,level);
            print_array(arr,size);
            if(parent!=rank)
             {
                 printf("\n i am the node %d withe height of  %d and i send my array to parent %d ",rank,level,parent);
                  MPI_Send(arr,size,MPI_INT,parent,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
             }
            printf("\n");
         }     
}

/*************************************/
int main()
{
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int rank;
    int comm_size;
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&comm_size);

    if(rank==0)
    {
        int rootHeight=0;
        int nodeCount=1;
        while (nodeCount<comm_size)
        {
            nodeCount++;
        }
        rootHeight=(int)log2(nodeCount);
        printf("i am the root with the rank of %d and height of %d\n",rank,rootHeight);
        tree(arr,10,rootHeight);
    }
    else 
    {
        int height;
        int massage[2];
        int newSize;
        MPI_Recv(massage,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        height=massage[0];
        newSize=massage[1];
        int* newArray = (int*)calloc(newSize,sizeof(int));
        MPI_Recv(newArray,newSize,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        tree(newArray,newSize,height);
        free(newArray);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

When I run the code with 4 processors the output is :

```
i am the root with the rank of 0 and height of 2

 enterig the divid process

 i am the node 0 with te Rank of 0 and height of 2 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

 enterig the divid process

 i am the node 0 with te Rank of 0 and height of 1 

1 2 3 4 5 

 i am the node 0 with the height of 0 and i have the array of : 

 1 2 


 i am the node 1 with the height of 0 and i have the array of : 

 3 4 5 

 i am the node 1 withe height of  0 and i send my array to parent 0 

 i am the parent node 0 with the height of 1 and i recieved form 1 the array :

 3 4 5 0 0 

 enterig the divid process

 i am the node 2 with te Rank of 2 and height of 1 

6 7 8 9 10 

 i am the node 2 with the height of 0 and i have the array of :
 
 6 7 



 i am the parent node 0 with the height of 2 and i recieved form 2 the array :

 6 7 8 9 10 0 104993 0 0 0 

 i am the node 3 with the height of 0 and i have the array of : 

 8 9 10 

 i am the node 3 withe height of  0 and i send my array to parent 2 

 i am the node 2 withe height of  1 and i send my array to parent 0 

 i am the parent node 2 with the height of 1 and i recieved form 3 the array :

 8 9 10 0 0
```

Comment: Please include examples of desired output, vs. the current output including "some garbage along side of Array elements".

Comment: the size of the array you receive and print is sometimes too large. use a real status instead of `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` and make sure you do not receive less data than expected.

Comment: also you do two `MPI_Recv(...,MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ...)` in a row, and seems to expect they will both receive data from the **same** sender. long story short, this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: but i use different Tags and Buffer. doesn`t it make any difference ? also how could i use MPI_status status in order to make sure ? thank alot

Comment: use `status.MPI_SOURCE` to get the sender, and `MPI_Get_count()` to get the number of `MPI_INT` received.